# Does the diameter of a coil affect the voltage it generates when a magnetic field passes it?

Tags: generator, coil, induction

If two wires of equal length (let's say 1m) are wound with different diameters (3cm and 6cm) to form a coil, if equal alternating magnetic fields passes through both of them, will they generate the same voltage?

For example:

- First coil: 3cm diameter 100 turns
- Second coil: 6cm diameter 50 turns

Comment: you cannot get 100 turns on a 3 cm core with 1 m length wire ... it would be closer to 10 turns

Comment: @jsotola Don't let your arbitrary definition of \$\pi\$ distract you from the question 

Comment: The example is just so you can have an idea of my question. I didn't do any calculation when I gave it.

Answer (score 1):

> *Does the diameter of a coil affects the voltage it generates when
> magnetic field passes it*

If the same rate of change of flux is applied to both coils **with the same number of turns** then both have to generate the same terminal voltage as per laws of induction: -

$$E = -N\dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}$$

Nearly always in practical examples of (say near-field but loose coupling), the larger diameter coil (same number of turns) will produce the larger voltage because it has a larger area and inevitably more flux will pass through that larger surface.

However, if you took the example of a regular transformer, nearly all the flux will pass through a secondary coil that is either tightly wrapped around the core or loosely wrapped. It could be quite loosely wrapped and still (pretty much) produce the same terminal voltage for the same number of turns.

But, if you tried to draw current from the loosely wrapped coil, because of the increased leakage inductance, its terminal voltage would be significantly lower than a coil that was tightly wrapped around the core.

**If the number of turns are unequal then different induced voltages will be produced.**

Comment: the induction formula indicates that the larger coil produces larger voltage. The flux rises with the square of the diameter, while the number of turns decrease linearly.

Comment: From the example I gave in the question, does that mean that the 6cm diameter 50 turns coil will have a higher voltage than the 3cm diameter 100 turns coil or will the voltage generated be the same if the same magnetic field passes through both of them?

Comment: Kindly ignore the length of the wire I wrote in the question. I simply used that to show that both coils use the same length of wire

Comment: @Daenny if both receive the same changing flux (and I mean the exactly the same) then the coil with more turns has induced a higher voltage. \$V = -N\dfrac{d/Phi}{dt}\$ is the formula where N is number of turns. If they don't receive the same flux then things will be different. Quote from my answer: **If the number of turns are unequal then different induced voltages will be produced**; more turns equals more voltage induced.

Comment: Thanks @Andyaka I looked up the formula you shared and I was wondering, won't the πr2 mean that the wider radius with 50 turns will produce more voltage? https://www.coursehero.com/study-guides/physics/23-5-electric-generators/

Comment: @Daenny if the same rate of change of flux is seen by larger diameter coil and smaller diameter coil, it won't make any difference if the turns are the same; the open circuit induced voltage will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

For the case of circular windings and spatially constant magnetic field, **the produced voltage would linearly rise with the winding diameter**.

Tight coils with many windings are used if you need to pickup a very localized magnetic field, such as the field from a point source or field through a transformer yoke.

Comment: From the example I gave in the question, does that mean that the 6cm diameter 50 turns coil will have a higher voltage than the 3cm diameter 100 turns coil or will the voltage generated be the same if the same magnetic field passes through both of them?

Comment: @Daenny the voltage of the 6cm coil will be twice the voltage of the 3 cm coil

Comment: I think so too although I'm not a physics expert. πr2 x number of turns assuming the rest are constant is 1413 for the 6cm diameter and 706.5 for the 3cm diameter. I saw an example from here https://www.coursehero.com/study-guides/physics/23-5-electric-generators/ not sure if I'm correct though